# Best way to get the unit vector of a given vector in tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Suppose I have a coordinate in tikz 3d which I interpret as a vector, for example

`\coordinate (v) at (3,2,9);`

What's the best way to get the unit vector pointing into the same direction?

My first idea was to use the `let` syntax, but this doesn't work in 3d.

For example

`\path let \p1 = (v) in ($1/(x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^3)^(0.5)*(v)$) coordinate (vv);`

Anyhow I am looking for a more easy to use solution than using `let` for this...

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54804/4011

Comment: I posted an update which works, but isn' too elegant.

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\newcommand{\unitvec}[3][->]% [options], start point, vector
{   \xdef\mysum{0}
    \foreach \c in  {#3}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysquare}{\mysum+pow(\c,2)}
        \xdef\mysum{\mysquare}
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myveclen}{sqrt(\mysum)}
    \draw[#1] (#2) -- ($1/\myveclen*(#3)$);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (3,6,2);
\unitvec[-latex,red,thick]{0,0,0}{3,6,2}

\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (-2,4,3);
\unitvec[->,blue,thick]{0,0,0}{-2,4,3}

\draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (-1,-4,-1);
\unitvec[-stealth,green,thick]{0,0,0}{-1,-4,-1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Here's a version with a new `\Coordinate(<name>)(<vector>)`. To work it now needs `\Unitvec`, as `\unitvec` only works with direct numbers.

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\def\Coordinate(#1)(#2)% name, vector
{   \expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}
    \coordinate (#1) at (#2);
}

% for use with \Coordinates
\newcommand{\Unitvec}[3][->]% [options], start point, vector
{   \xdef\mysum{0}
    \foreach \myconstant [count=\mycount] in    #3
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysquare}{\mysum+pow(\myconstant,2)}
        \xdef\mysum{\mysquare}
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myveclen}{sqrt(\mysum)}
    \draw[#1] (#2) -- ($1/\myveclen*(#3)$);
}

%for use with direct numbers, e.g. \unitvec[-latex,red,thick]{0,0,0}{3,6,2}
\newcommand{\unitvec}[3][->]% [options], start point, vector
{   \xdef\mysum{0}
    \foreach \c in  {#3}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysquare}{\mysum+pow(\c,2)}
        \xdef\mysum{\mysquare}
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myveclen}{sqrt(\mysum)}
    \draw[#1] (#2) -- ($1/\myveclen*(#3)$);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Coordinate(o)(0,0,0)
\Coordinate(a)(3,6,2)
\Coordinate(b)(-2,4,3)
\Coordinate(c)(-1,-4,-1)

\draw[-latex] (o) -- (a);
\Unitvec[-latex,red,thick]{\o}{\a}

\draw[->] (o) -- (b);
\Unitvec[->,blue,thick]{\o}{\b}

\draw[-stealth] (o) -- (c);
\Unitvec[-stealth,green,thick]{\o}{\c}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

Ecactly the same as before.

### Please note:

`\Coordinate` uses `\xdef` to store the vectors, so it will overwrite existing commands without hesitation. Furthermore, it uses commands, so you'll have to write `\a` instead of `a`. It also creates a regular `\coordinate`. If you just need the point on the canvas, you can use `a` (as in the `\draw` commands), if the true 3D position matters, you should use `\a` (like for `\unitvec`). Also, using things like `-` or `8` in a coordinate name, which works in `TikZ` does not work with `edef`, so only use letters.

Comment: The `\unitvec` macro should take something like `(v)` as argument.

Comment: Then you have a problem, as Tikz internally uses only 2D coordinates. [In this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54804/extract-coordinates-from-3d-point), **Andrew Stacey** discusses a possible way around this using some experimental code.

Comment: Even though the coordinate is given with 3D entries if you place a temporary coordinate at the tip, it's saved as a 2D coordinate so you can get the angle via `atan2` and use `(angle:1)` to draw.

Comment: @percusse I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @percusse: Nice idea, but due to perspective the (canvas) length of a unit vector is not neccessarily equal one. Probably `($1/<veclen>*(<vec>)$)` will work.

Comment: @student 3D library of TikZ accepts 3D inputs but converts them (or projects them) onto the 2D plane. Hence if you put a coordinate at the tip of the line that is drawn using 3D point input, it would still be a 2D point. So that would give the direction that unit vector points to. Example: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1) coordinate (a);
\draw[yellow] (0,0) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}`. Then you can say for example, `\draw[blue,thick] (0,0) -- ($(0,0)!1cm!(a)$);` to go 1cm along that direction. But as Tom mentioned this might not necessarily be 1cm.

Comment: @tom-bombadil I know it's quite an old subject but anyway, I can't get it working outside of origin. In fact you need to subtract starting point coords from those of the end point. And thus the `\unitvec` macro wont work outside of (0,0,0). I tried with a shifted scope but then it seems the points aren't shifted due to the `\xdef` in the definition `\Coordinate` (I guess...).
BTW, wouldn't it be easier to use `\draw[#1] (#2) -- ($(#2)!1/\myveclen!(#3)$);` (again, in case the starting point is outside the origin...)