# pgfplots: drawing multiple vectors with corresponding unit vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, calculations, coordinates

Suppose you have a couple of 3D-vectors given by their start and endpoints. Now you want to define a command that draws one of these vectors together with its respective unit vector from the same origin.

A similar problem has been answered before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75971/139258) - however the solution only works for vectors starting from `(0,0,0)`.

As I struggled to apply the presented `\foreach`-approach on two given coordinates simultaniously and given the age of the solution, I approached this problem using the `calculator`-package.

I'm getting a functioning output for a single vector - unfortunately only the last unit vector (called by `\vecuvec{1,1,0}{0,2,1}`) is getting drawn correctly for multiple executions of `\vecuvec` as the coordinates `(\sola,\solb,\solc)` seem to be overwritten by the last execution of `\vecuvec`.

Is there a practical alternative by for example storing/accessing the coordinates in a different way or changing the scopes within the command `\vecuvec`?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% Draw vector and corresponding unitvector
\newcommand{\vecuvec}[2] %start point, end point (of vector)
{   \VECTORSUB(#2)(#1)(\sola,\solb,\solc)
    \UNITVECTOR(\sola, \solb, \solc)(\sola,\solb,\solc)
    %arrow in blue
    \draw[->,thick,blue] (#1) -- (#2); 
    %corresponding unit-vector in red:
    \draw[->, thick,red] (#1) -- ($(#1)+(\sola,\solb,\solc)$); 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={0,1,...,4}, ytick={0,1,...,4}, ztick={0,1,...,4},
             xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=4, zmin=0,zmax=4]
    \vecuvec{3,1,0}{4,2,1};
    \vecuvec{2,2,2}{4,3,3};
    \vecuvec{1,1,0}{0,2,1}; %only the last one works as intended
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image: tikzpicture with three different vectors and their corresponding unit vectors (flawed)]

Here for the blue vectors only the leftmost has its unit vector drawn correctly (in red).

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs?  (Look for [`axis direction cs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf#pgfp.axis:direction:cs))

Comment: @HenriMenke Perhaps I'm missing something, but how does that help here?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `(#1) -- ($(#1)+(\sola,\solb,\solc)$)` is a relative coordinate calculation which does not work like this in `pgfplots`.  For relative coordinates you need `axis direction cs` as explained in the manual.  So I guess the correct behaviour would be obtained by `(#1) -- ++(axis direction cs:\sola,\solb,\solc)`

Comment: @HenriMenke a) No it's not, you're thinking about `(#1) -- +(\sola,\solb,\solc)`, which is a different thing from what the OP is using (`calc` library syntax). b) The problem here is I, would think, delayed expansion, similar to why you need special care for loops inside an `axis`. Note that the third of those work fine, and that the other two unit vectors are the same as the third. Remove the third, and the second works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same trick used for `\draw` macros in loops (see `pgfplots`  manual section 8.1 *Utility commands*) works here as well it seems, i.e.

```
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[->, thick,red] (#1) -- ($(#1)+(\sola,\solb,\solc)$);}
    \temp
```

which causes immediate expansion of `\sola` etc.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% Draw vector and corresponding unitvector
\newcommand{\vecuvec}[2] %start point, end point (of vector)
{   \VECTORSUB(#2)(#1)(\sola,\solb,\solc)
    \UNITVECTOR(\sola, \solb, \solc)(\sola,\solb,\solc)
    %arrow in blue
    \draw[->,thick,blue] (#1) -- (#2); 
    %corresponding unit-vector in red:
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[->, thick,red] (#1) -- ($(#1)+(\sola,\solb,\solc)$);}
    \temp
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={0,1,...,4}, ytick={0,1,...,4}, ztick={0,1,...,4},
             xmin=0,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=4, zmin=0,zmax=4]
    \vecuvec{3,1,0}{4,2,1};
    \vecuvec{2,2,2}{4,3,3};
    \vecuvec{1,1,0}{0,2,1}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```