# TikZ trapezoid transformation (vanishing point)

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Within a TikZ drawing, I want to distort a 2D rasterimage (from
`\includegraphics`) so that it appears to be rotated by 90° around the
vertical axis in 3D (it should look perpendicular to the sheet of
paper).  I've managed to achieve a transformation with `yslant` and
`xscale`, like the following.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (term) at (0,0) [yslant=-0.7,xscale=0.3] 
        {\includegraphics[width=40mm]{image.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which distorts an image like this

```
                            a    
                            |\             
a---------b                 | \  
|         |                 |  \ 
|         |      -->        c   b
|         |                  \  |
c---------d                   \ |
                               \|
                                d
```

I'm not really happy with this: The distance |a-c| should be *smaller*
than |b-d|.  How can I achieve this?

There is an example of a
[cuboid](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cuboid/) which looks
pretty nice, but it seems useless to distort an imported raster image.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add signature, your username is included in the lower right of your Q.

Comment: The transformation you achieved would be the result of a [parallel projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection). You actually want to simulate a [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection#Perspective_projection)? I don’t think this is doable with vanilla TikZ options. You probably need to calculate these transformations.

Comment: This is not doable via PDF transformation (TikZ and PGF use PDF transformations). You need to transform your rasterimage via Gimp (or Photoshop).

Comment: Maybe a duplicate : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52578/perspective-transform ? Nope you have an image, nevermind

Comment: Maybe you could draw your rectangle in perspective using the 3D capabilities of Tikz? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59406/19156

Comment: I think this is best done with [ImageMagick’s convert tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Using `example-image.png` from the [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package one can do `convert example-image.png -distort Perspective "0,0,0,40 0,300,0,260 400,0,400,0 400,300,400,300" example-image-distorted.png`. Though, I couldn’t get the now black background color to be either white or transparent. I’m sure, it is somehow possible.