# Gradient colour in tikz pgfplot marker

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to replicate the dual colours of the circles in this graph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={40pt 12pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=1.9359375in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
xlabel={Partition},
ymin=0,
ymax=5,
ytick={1,...,5},
xtick={0,0.5,...,2},
ylabel={No Partition}
]
\addplot [
color=red,
only marks,
mark=ball,
mark options={solid, line width=1pt},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.752891515 1.119390244\\
0.918362178 1.65402439\\
0.794259181 4.527682927\\
1.10865344 0.515142276\\
1.621612495 1.002439024\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
line width=1pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.6 2.64921945346413\\
0.7 2.44758628403132\\
0.8 2.24595311459851\\
0.9 2.04431994516571\\
1 1.8426867757329\\
1.1 1.64105360630009\\
1.2 1.43942043686729\\
1.3 1.23778726743448\\
1.4 1.03615409800167\\
1.5 0.834520928568865\\
1.6 0.632887759136058\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

So far I have this:

[image]

Does anyone know of inbuilt gradient options for colouring? If not I'll settle for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare your own plot marks using

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{<name>}{<code that draws the marks>}
```

For example, you could set

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{gradient}{
    \fill [
        draw=none,
        left color=red,
        right color=blue,
        shading angle=45
    ] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
}
```

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{gradient}{
    \fill [
        draw=none,
        left color=red,
        right color=blue,
        shading angle=45
    ] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfplotmarksize];
}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=1.9359375in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
xlabel={Partition},
ymin=0,
ymax=5,
ytick={1,...,5},
xtick={0,0.5,...,2},
ylabel={No Partition}
]
\addplot [
only marks, mark=gradient, mark size=5pt
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.752891515 1.119390244\\
0.918362178 1.65402439\\
0.794259181 4.527682927\\
1.10865344 0.515142276\\
1.621612495 1.002439024\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
line width=1pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.6 2.64921945346413\\
0.7 2.44758628403132\\
0.8 2.24595311459851\\
0.9 2.04431994516571\\
1 1.8426867757329\\
1.1 1.64105360630009\\
1.2 1.43942043686729\\
1.3 1.23778726743448\\
1.4 1.03615409800167\\
1.5 0.834520928568865\\
1.6 0.632887759136058\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks again Jake! That's just what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jake, is there an easy way of having a radial gradient and make the outer color transparent, so each point looks like a smooth point?

Comment: @alfC: Does it have to be transparent, or would white work?

Comment: Learning how to make it white will help, but the ultimate goal is to make the points smooth and able to partially supper impose in order to form complicated larger blobs without sharp borders.

Comment: @alfC: For white, you can just do `\fill [
        draw=white,
        inner color=black,
        outer color=white,...` (or for finer control, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115340/2552). I'm not sure about the transparency, though, you might want to open a new question for that.

Answer (score 4):

You need first to declare a shading:

```
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{2cm}{color(0pt)=(blue); color(2cm)=(yellow)}
```

And then a new marker:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymarker}{%
    \begin{pgfscope}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{-\pgfplotmarksize}}{\pgfpoint{2\pgfplotmarksize}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}
        \pgfshadepath{myshading}{-45}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

So your MWE should be something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={40pt 12pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshading}{2cm} 
    {color(0pt)=(blue); color(2cm)=(yellow)} 

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymarker}{%
    \begin{pgfscope}
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-\pgfplotmarksize}{-\pgfplotmarksize}}{\pgfpoint{2\pgfplotmarksize}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}
        \pgfshadepath{myshading}{-45}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfplotmarksize}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=1.9359375in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=2,
xlabel={Partition},
ymin=0,
ymax=5,
ytick={1,...,5},
xtick={0,0.5,...,2},
ylabel={No Partition}
]


\addplot [
color=red,
only marks,
mark=mymarker,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.752891515 1.119390244\\
0.918362178 1.65402439\\
0.794259181 4.527682927\\
1.10865344 0.515142276\\
1.621612495 1.002439024\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
dashed,
line width=1pt,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.6 2.64921945346413\\
0.7 2.44758628403132\\
0.8 2.24595311459851\\
0.9 2.04431994516571\\
1 1.8426867757329\\
1.1 1.64105360630009\\
1.2 1.43942043686729\\
1.3 1.23778726743448\\
1.4 1.03615409800167\\
1.5 0.834520928568865\\
1.6 0.632887759136058\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

And will produce this:

[image: result]

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution! Your approach will be useful for something else I have in mind :)