# Multiple 2D Gaussian ellipses in 3D plot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'd like to plot different bivariate Gaussian distributions as shaded 2D ellipses at different points in 3D space.
The 2D ellipses I would plot like Jake suggests in [Gaussian ellipsoids using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115340/gaussian-ellipsoids-using-tikz), but technically that is already a 3D plot. Is there a possibility to extend this method?

---

I came up with the following example (left: example how I like the ellipses to be orientated, taken from https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03986, right: my ansatz):

[image][image: Output of above .tex-file]

Two main points are that

- the colormap is not actually transparent and one cannot see the axis of the outer coordinate system any more,
- and that I would like to have the ellipses at a fixed point *y* in the *xz*-plane (this means that the bottom line of the black rectangles should be parallel to the *x*-axis and compressed accordingly).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(transparent); color(1.cm)=(red)}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
    declare function={bivar(\ma,\sa,\mb,\sb)=
        1/(2*pi*\sa*\sb) * exp(-((x-\ma)^2/\sa^2 + (y-\mb)^2/\sb^2))/2;}]
% Outer coordinate system
\begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    axis lines = middle,
    view={120}{30},
    domain = -10:10,
    zmin = -5, zmax = 5,
    xlabel = $x$, ylabel = $y$, zlabel = $z$,
    x label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.)},anchor=north east},
    y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.)},anchor=north west},
    z label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.)},anchor=south},
    ]
    \coordinate (origin1) at (axis cs:0,-10,0);
    \coordinate (origin2) at (axis cs:0,10,0);
    \addplot3[no markers,opacity=0]{0}; % <- without this pseudo plot, the outer coordinate system does not work
\end{axis}
% Bivariate distribution 1
\begin{axis}[
    at={(origin1)}, anchor={center},
    width=3cm, height=3cm,
    scale only axis,
    axis equal image,
    hide axis,
    colormap name=whitered,
    view={0}{90},
    enlargelimits=false,
    domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf, draw=none, samples=19, shader=interp, patch type=bilinear] {bivar(0,.1,0,.6)};
\end{axis}
% Bivariate distribution 2
\begin{axis}[
    at={(origin2)}, anchor={center},
    width=3cm, height=3cm,
    scale only axis,
    axis equal image,
    hide axis,
    colormap name=whitered,
    view={0}{90},
    enlargelimits=false,
    domain=-1.5:1.5, y domain=-1.5:1.5,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf, draw=none, samples=19, shader=interp, patch type=bilinear] {bivar(0,.2,0,.3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you need to add the beginning of a MWE.

Comment: I'm not really asking for a complete solution, rather for a way to tackle the problem. Jake's mentioned answer depends on having a certain angle onto a coloured 3D plot, which is not feasible the way I want to do it. The only way I can think of is produce separate image files of the ellipses and insert them sheared and at different positions in a new 3D plot.

Comment: @dodi please dont add external links, if you want to add images/codes please do that so within this site. Other links tend to die over-time. Moreover, please show us what you have tried so-far, atleast something for us to being with. I think that would really be helpful, instead of us starting everything from scratch.

Comment: Answer to your question: yes, it is possible. If you want a more detailed answer, consider writing a more detailed question with some code that shows what you've tried and has some data in such that the one writing an answer does not have to make it up.

Comment: With tikz-3dplot you can use \tdplotresetrotatedcoordsorigin and \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords to draw 2D ellipses in 3D.

Comment: Thanks all for the hints, I tried to improve the question.