# Tikz create perspective grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

i was wondering how i could create a `perspective 2D grid` like this blue one on the left:

https://tinytutorials.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/illustrator-cs5-perspective-grid-manipulating-the-perspective-grid/

with `Tikz`. My current approach:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=2.5mm,gray,very thin] (4,0) grid (7,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately it isn't possible to rotate the `draw` in 3D.

Comment: Peripherally related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319172/gimp-like-perspective-transform-in-tikz

Comment: This should be relatively straight forward, just drawing the appropriate straight lines, using the `tikz` package.  Show us what coding you have tried, and we can answer more precisely.

Comment: I edited my initial question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Could you please complete your code so it is compilable?

Answer (score 7):

Not very efficient. Elegance is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [count=\ino from 0] in {-5,-4,...,5}
  {
    \draw [Cerulean] (\i,-10,0) -- (0,0,0) \foreach \j in {0,...,10} {coordinate [pos={\j/10}] (c-\ino-\j)};
  }
  \foreach \i in {0,...,7} \draw [Cerulean] (c-10-\i) -- (c-0-\i);
  \draw [Cerulean] (c-0-0) -- ++(0,7,0) \foreach \j in {0,...,7} {coordinate [pos={\j/7}] (a\j)} -- (0,0,0) \foreach \i in {0,...,10} {coordinate [pos={\i/10}] (b\i)};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,7} \path (a\i) -- (0,0,0) \foreach \j in {0,...,10} {coordinate [pos={\j/10}] (d-\i-\j)};
  \foreach \i in {1,...,7} \draw [Cerulean] (a\i) -- (d-\i-7) (c-0-\i) -- (b\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: perspective grid]