# How to draw a wooden cube with one corner cut off and shaded?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the figure above, a wooden cube with one orner cut off and shaded.

[image]

I can only draw the cube, I can't remove a part of the cube by a plane.

```
\documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{tikz}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]

   \draw[thick,black] (4,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) -- (4,4,0);

   \draw[thick,black]  (4,0,0) -- (4,0,-4) -- (4,4,-4) -- (4,4,0) -- cycle;

   \draw[thick,black](0,4,0) -- (0,4,-4) -- (4,4,-4);

   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (4,0,-4) -- (0,0,-4)-- (0,4,-4);

   \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-4); 

     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not get me wrong, but in the future please consider asking clearer questions. If you ask for a shaded corner and end up accepting an answer that has no shaded corner, then this is your choice, but a bit odd for those who provided what you were asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very short code with `pst-solides3d`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

 \begin{document}

  \psset{viewpoint=50 75 30 rtp2xyz, Decran=25, lightsrc=viewpoint}
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
 \psSolid[action=draw*, object=cube, RotZ=40, fillcolor=ForestGreen!80, trunccoeff=.5, trunc=0]%
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This draws such a truncated cube. It uses an orthographic view.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta,perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{15},line join=round,
    declare function={a=4;b=2;}]
 \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (a,0,-a) -- (0,0,-a)-- (0,a,-a);
 \draw[style=dashed, color=black] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-a); 
 \draw[thick,black]  (a,0,0) -- (a,0,-a) -- (a,a,-a) -- (a,a,-b);
 \draw[thick,black] (a,a-b,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a-b,a,0);
 \draw[thick,black](0,a,0) -- (0,a,-a) -- (a,a,-a);
 \draw[thick,pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4.5pt}]}] 
 (a,a,-b) -- (a-b,a,0) -- (a,a-b,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the view angles to some extent (if you overdo it, the dashed lines will be in the foreground) and change the cube dimension `a` and the dimension of the missing corner `b`. For instance, with `3d view={150}{15}` and `declare function={a=4;b=1;}` you will get

[image]

Please note that `patterns.meta` requires a not too old TeX installation. If you have a rather old version, load `patterns` instead of `patterns.meta`, and use e.g. `pattern=north east lines` instead of `pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4.5pt}]}`.

Comment: Hello
I don't know the prospect "perspective". Where is the doc?

Comment: @rpapa Section **64 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of the pgfmanual v3.1.5, starts on p. 738. I am only using the `3d view`. One could also use a perspective view, but judging from the screen shot the OP seems to ask for an orthographic view.

Comment: merci
je vais regarder

Comment: @rpapa 我的榮幸 ;-)

Comment: Some ten years ago the 3D library was either not there or I did not kew about it, so I drew the cubes of [Schönhage matrix multiplication](https://www.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/gs005/gs005.pdf) using projections and shrinkage in 2D. Not my proudest feat...

Comment: @OlegLobachev I think that the 3d library was around for a while (whether or not 10 years I do not know) but it only entered the manual perhaps 2 years back. The older version had a bug. The perspective library, which serves a somewhat different purpose, emerged from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447114/194703), so it is much more recent. For orthonormal projections one can equally well use the `tikz-3dplot` package, which first appeared 2009-11-09. Since it autoloads `3d`, so perhaps `3d` is that old.

Comment: It was probably my illiteracy and ignorance and not a missing feature, yes. Here is [the actual image](https://imgur.com/cD9gRoe), anyway.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I think it looks fine. If you used 3d coordinates, i.e. coordinates with 3 entries, you only need to change the projection to get an orthographic result.

Comment: Thank you! That's the point: I used 2d coordinates! Basically, I did the projection math myself, but for a different kind of a projection. ;)